# C# (Visual Studio 2010) not finding an included reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference

I'm trying to write code for forms without using MS Designer.

When I compile, I'm consistently getting the same errors:

> The type System.ComponentModel.* is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

This will appear for IComponent, ISynchronizeInvoke, and Component. I think I have referenced it.

I've tried removing the reference and re-applying it, and switching to earlier versions of .net.  It has to be something in my environment, but I cannot find it.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;


public class EmptyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{

    public EmptyForm()
    {
    }
    public static int Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new EmptyForm());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[image: Screen shot of my Visual Studio.]

Comment: `System.ComponentModel.Component` is a **type**, not an assembly.  `System.ComponentModel.Composition` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Why would you code your Windows Forms manually(without the designer)?

Comment: @RyanGates There are plenty of cases to do this, one of which I often use is dynamic form creation.

Comment: I know it's not a rule, it's more of a personal preference, but I'd suggest using the designer before trying to code everything from scratch until you get comfortable. And even though it's easy to do *evil* things with the designer like many would say, it all depends on how you use it.

Answer (score 5):

As the error *clearly* states, you need to add a reference to **System**.

Comment: I suppose it could be more user friendly.

Comment: hmm i thought "You must add a reference to system" was pretty friendly my self

Answer (score 3):

To add a reference, just right click on **References** and choose **Add Reference**. There you can add the relevant references.

You have the `using` directive, but you are not referencing the assembly.

Comment: hattenn has the correct answer.  simply add the System reference to the instructions hattenn provided, then put `using System;`

Comment: @Magnum: Actually, the `using` statement is not necessary; none of those errors are about namespaces.